# Aggregate on a single column except one value in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in the following format,

```
store_num   pos_date                reward_id   retailer_id reward_name
1236     2020-05-10 00:00:00.000     3              21          Reward1
1236    2020-05-11 00:00:00.000      1              21          Reward2
1236    2020-05-12 00:00:00.000      4              21          Reward3
1236    2020-05-12 00:00:00.000      5              21          Reward4
1236    2020-05-12 00:00:00.000      6              21          CONTROL
```

I want my query to group by reward_name where all rewards except `CONTROL` one should be aggregated and `CONTROL` should be aggregated as a separate.

I want result in the following format,

```
reward_name     profit
All Offers  Value
Control     Value
```

Can this be done in a single query?

Comment: Show the results you want.

Comment: Did you try anything? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a `case` expression` for aggregation.  I don't know the specific results, but for instance:

```
select (case when reward_name = 'CONTROL' then 'CONTROL' else 'OTHER' end),
       count(*)
from t
group by (case when reward_name = 'CONTROL' then 'CONTROL' else 'OTHER' end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT case when reward_name='CONTROL' then 'CONTROL' else 'All Offers' end as reward_name
       SUM(trackable_return_count) as trackable_returns,
       SUM(purchase_count_after_return) as purchase_after_returns,
       CAST(SUM(purchase_amount_after_return) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS purchase_after_returns_amount,
       CAST(SUM(profit_after_return) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS gross_profit_purchase_after_returns,
       CAST(SUM(purchase_count_after_return)* 100.0/NULLIF(SUM(trackable_return_count),0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS purchase_after_returns_rate,
       CAST(SUM(purchase_amount_after_return)* 100.0/NULLIF(SUM(trackable_return_count),0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS sales_return_rate,
       CAST(SUM(profit_after_return)* 100.0/NULLIF(SUM(trackable_return_count),0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS gross_profit_return_rate
       FROM 
           incent_summary
       WHERE
            pos_date >= DATEADD(day, @period , CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
            AND pos_date <= GETDATE()
       group by case when reward_name='CONTROL' then 'CONTROL' else 'All Offers' end
```